# Advertencia de matplotlib al mostrar gráfica

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, ipython

Trabajo con Spyder.
Quiero mostrar por pantalla una gráfica que genero con matplotlib. El script que utilizo es:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y1 = [1, 7, 3, 4]
x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3]

graph = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.grid(True)
plt.axis('tight')
graph.show()
```

Al ejecutarlo, me aparece la imagen en la terminal de IPython junto con un mensaje de advertencia:

> UserWarning: matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, so
>   cannot show the figure   "matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI
>   backend, "

¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: %matplotlib inline yo solo puse eso en la parte donde importo las librerias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas usando un backend inline para que la gráfica se muestre en la consola ipython. El problema es que [`matplotlib.figure.Figure.show()`](http://matplotlib.figure.Figure) está diseñado para mostrar la figura usando una GUI, si no usas un GUI backend se lanza un `warning` y no muestra nada.

> For non-GUI backends, this does nothing, in which case a warning will be issued if warn is True (default).

Puedes usar `plt.show()` en su lugar (seguirás pudiendo usar la instancia `graph` para guardar la figura por ejemplo sin problemas). Si quieres que se abra una ventana para mostrar la gráfica (GUI) deberás configurar un GUI backend adecuado (tkAgg, Qt4Agg, Qt5Agg, GTKAgg, GTK3Agg, WXAgg, ... ) :

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('tkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y1 = [1, 7, 3, 4]
x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3]

graph = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.grid(True)
plt.axis('tight')
graph.show()
```

---

**Edición:**

En Spyder se pude determinar que backend usar de forma gráfica en las opciones de configuración del IDE:

1. Ir a <kbd>Herramienta</kbd> -> <kbd>Preferencias</kbd>:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. En el panel de la izquierda seleccionar <kbd>Terminal de IPython</kbd>.
3. A la derecha ir a la pestaña <kbd>Gráficas</kbd> y en la sección Salida gráfica seleccionar el backend en el menú desplegable o la opción `Auto`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. Reiniciar el kernel de IPython:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una forma alternativa es usando un "magic command" en la terminal de IPython:

```
%matplotlib auto
```

Esto no necesita reiniciar el kernel, si luego quieres volver al modo inline basta con volver a ingresar:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

> **Nota:** esto se hace en la consola de IPython, no en el editor de código. Este método funcionará también en IPython fuera de Spyder.

Comment: Entendido. Pero haciendo lo que comentas, me da otros errores: _UserWarning: 
This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect because the backend has already
been chosen; matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time._ y  _UserWarning: matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure
  "matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend_

Comment: Por si sirve de algo, uso Spider a través de Anaconda.

Comment: @Zhisi el backend solo puede ser seleccionado al inicio, en tu caso la consola ya inicia de forma automática con el modo inline, por lo que no te deja luego cambiar. He editado la respuesta añadiendo información específica para Spyder e IPython. En este caso lo que indico al inicio de la respuesta no es necesario. Un saludo.